# Combining LESS and CSS in same HTML

Tags: css, less

I can't seem to find an answer to this anywhere online.

I have already written all the CSS code for my site and don't have time to reformat it into LESS, however I've just discovered LESS and how it could be useful for certain functions. I want to edit forms on my html page with LESS for example, but everything else is fine with the CSS I've written. Is there any way to combine the two? Can I have CSS affecting certain parts of the HTML page and LESS affecting others if I load in 2 separate files?

Comment: Absolutely. LESS ultimately just compiles down to raw CSS anyway :) You may find this article on combining the two with `gulp` useful: https://ypereirareis.github.io/blog/2015/10/22/gulp-merge-less-sass-css/

Comment: to compile LESS into CSS are you using a build system such as grunt or gulp? if so you can concat the compiled LESS with the CSS in the output file

Comment: Not so far Brian McCall I haven't started coding the LESS yet, but will try that

Comment: It's a little unclear on how you're interpreting what LESS is. Less compiles into CSS. You can leave your _"old"_ CSS alone and any new additions with LESS you would just add to the bottom of your _"old"_ CSS file. To make this happen all you would have to do is rename your previous CSS file from `style.css` to `style.less` and then compile `style.less` to `style.css`.

Comment: @ObsidianAge thanks I'll take a look at that

Comment: LESS is not another language. It is simply pre-compiled CSS... you can mix normal CSS and LESS in the same file and pass it through the compiler, and the LESS parts will be compiled into CSS. It's like writing raw HTML in a Markdown document :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are understandably, but completely, confused as to what LESS actually is :) LESS "is" CSS. In so much as it's a document you write with all sorts of shortcuts, variables and functions which is then compiled (turned into) CSS.

So when you write LESS, you are writing CSS, but with a bunch of shorthand.

There are various methods of compiling the LESS into CSS, including [winLess](http://winless.org/) and (my choice) [Grunt](https://gruntjs.com/). I am sure there are others. The way I have Grunt setup it also mins (compresses) the CSS at the same time it compiles. It also compiles automatically, as you save the .less file.

Less is saved as a .less file. Once it is compiled into (well... "as") the .css file you should not, as a rule, edit that .css file... just edit the .less file from whence it came! (and recompile) :)

The take away here is that LESS is a CSS pre-processor language (there are others, notably SASS). A shorthand, and powerful, way to ultimately simply write CSS.

Some points:

1. CSS is actually valid LESS. You can simply rename the CSS file to LESS, and compile it, and you will end up with a matching CSS file. (Then in the LESS file you can start taking advantages of "shorthand" features, all the file compiling into...still...the same CSS file. [suggested by @caesay]
2. You would never actually *include* a LESS file into an html file. Remember LESS is only there to be compiled into a CSS file... which you do include.

Comment: you missed the key point here i think - CSS is also valid LESS, so when switching a css code base into less, you can just rename the files and start adding new styles using less features.

Comment: Yes that's true. In fact sometimes I convert existing CSS into LESS, and this is how I start. With the CSS file, which I name .less, set up the conversion process and then start "lessing" out the css file :)